# How I express these sentences in logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$A: $ "**A**melia goes to birthday party"

$B: $ "**B**art goes to birthday party"

$C: $ "**C**hris goes to birthday party"

$D: $ "**D**iana goes to birthday party"

Let's say I want write this in logic language: *"If Amelia and Bart go to birthday party, then Chris or Diana also go to birthday party".*

I do it like this: $(A \wedge B) \rightarrow (C \vee D)$

Now If I need to write this in logic: *"Bart may never go alone to birthday party."* I'm confused because I don't know how to interpret this correctly. I have thought about simply writing: $\neg B$, but this would mean "Bart does not go to birthday party".

Then I thought I could interpret it that way better: "If Bart goes to birthday party, then at least someone else goes to birthday party too".

This in logic should be:

$$B \rightarrow ((A\wedge C \wedge D) \vee (A \wedge C) \vee (A \wedge D) \vee (C \wedge D) \vee (A) \vee (C) \vee (D))$$

Is it fine like that or completely wrong? I have thought about this for a while myself but I'm not sure! :c

Comment: I think it is correct! Bart may never go alone means that if he does go, someone else goes with him, at least one person. And that is exactly what you've written!

Comment: @hugh_maths Thanks for quick answer:) I have thought about adding an OR to that whole thing, so $((B \rightarrow (..)) \vee \neg B)$ to also have the case that Bart does not go there at all. But this is soo weird I'm really confused and can't say if that's a better solution:s

Comment: I really think the case "if Bart goes" is enough for what you want to write.

Comment: By not writing the case "if Bart doesn't go" you are simply saying that there are no restrictions in case he does not go. So, since you only have restrictions in case he goes, I think what you've written in the first place is good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its correct but it would be simpler if you wrote:
$B \rightarrow (A\vee C\vee D)$.
Since this also encompasses the other cases that you have written in your formula.

Answer (score 2):

One way to say it would be the statement. "It is not the case that B goes to the party and none of A, or C or D go to the party".

$\neg (B\wedge(\neg A\wedge\neg C\wedge \neg D))$

Or it could be written as "If B goes to the party, A or C or D go to the party"
This could be written as $B\implies (A\vee C\vee D)$

A third way is to say "if B goes, then it is not the case that none of A or C or D go"
This is expressed as $B\implies (\neg(\neg A\wedge\neg C\wedge \neg D))$